# Subquery inside a view

Tags: sql, view, subquery, between

I'm trying to create a view that lists all order ids, order dates, ship dates and company names for all orders created between August 14th, 2016 and August 23rd, 2016. The question says there needs to be a sub-query inside the view but I am not sure where or what is should be. Here is what I have so far:

```
    CREATE VIEW LAB9_VIEW
    AS
    SELECT orderid, orderdate, shippeddate, companyname
    FROM orders JOIN customers ON orders.customerid = customers.customerid
    WHERE (SELECT * from orders.orderdate) BETWEEN '2016-08-14' AND '2016- 
    08-23')
    WITH READ ONLY;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sub query inside a view will like this:

```
CREATE VIEW LAB9_VIEW
AS
SELECT orderid, orderdate, shippeddate, companyname
FROM orders JOIN customers ON orders.customerid = customers.customerid
WHERE orders.orderdate in (SELECT orderdate from orders where orderdate 
BETWEEN '2016-08-14' AND '2016-08-23')
WITH READ ONLY;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking to your code you could use  an AND clause in JOIN

```
CREATE VIEW LAB9_VIEW
AS
SELECT orderid, orderdate, shippeddate, companyname
FROM orders JOIN customers ON orders.customerid = customers.customerid
        AND orders.orderdate BETWEEN '2016-08-14' AND '2016- 08-23'

WITH READ ONLY;
```